# Resetting post data in Wordpress nested loops

Tags: nested-loops, wordpress

I'd be most grateful to anyone that can shed any light on this - I've studied the documentation and I can't see why this doesn't work.

I'm trying to create a navigation list which will look something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li> COUNTRY
    <ul>
      <li>CITY</li>
      <li>CITY</li>
      <li>CITY</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>TOWN</li>
      <li>TOWN</li>
      <li>TOWN</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

It requires 3 loops: a country loop, and then within that a city loop and a town loop (to list cities and towns within a country).

I'm using the following code:

```
<ul>

<?php
    # GET Countries
     $countryArgs = array(
       'category_name' => 'country',
       'posts_per_page' => -1,
       'meta_key' => 'country-menu-order',
       'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
       'order' => 'ASC'
     );
    $sidebar_nav_loop = new WP_Query($countryArgs);

    if( $sidebar_nav_loop->have_posts() ):

        while( $sidebar_nav_loop->have_posts() ): $sidebar_nav_loop->the_post();

        ?>

             <li class="<?php echo basename(get_permalink()); ?>"> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?> </a>

             <?php
             # GET RELATED Cities
             $cityArgs = array(
                            'post_type'         => 'post',
                            'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                            'meta_key'          => 'city-group',
                            'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
                            'order'             => 'ASC',
                            'meta_query'        => array(
                                array(
                                    'key'       => 'city-country',
                                    'value'     => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
                                    'compare'   => 'LIKE'
                                )
                            )
                        );
            $city_loop = new WP_Query($cityArgs);

            if( $city_loop->have_posts() ):

            ?>

                <ul>
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="sub"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

                <?php

                    while( $city_loop->have_posts() ): $city_loop->the_post(); ?>
                        <li>
                          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        </li>
                    <?php
                    endwhile;

                 echo "</ul>";

             endif;
             wp_reset_postdata();

            ?>

            <?php
             # GET RELATED towns
             $townArgs = array(
                            'post_type' => 'post',
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'meta_key'       => 'town-group',
                            'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
                            'order'          => 'ASC',
                            'meta_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'key' => 'town-country',
                                    'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                )
                            )
                        );
            $town_loop = new WP_Query($townArgs);

            if( $town_loop->have_posts() ):

            ?>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="sub"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
            <?php
            while( $town_loop->have_posts() ): $town_loop->the_post(); ?>
                <li>
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php
             endwhile;

             echo "</ul>";

             endif;
             wp_reset_postdata();

            ?>

            </li>

            <?php
      endwhile;
      endif;
      wp_reset_postdata();
?>

</ul>
```

I can get the country and city to work, or the country and town, but I can't get all three! To the best of my knowledge I've followed the documentation and reset the queries so they shouldn't conflict.

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your issue is the use of wp_reset_postdata(), and trying to use it to get the country ID the second time.  wp_reset_postdata()  will set the post data to be of the MAIN query. You may have interpreted that to mean YOUR main query (which is country) but that isn't the case. You actually have multiple nestings....

Main Query -> Country Query -> City Query AND Town Query

Try this:

After your first while, set a variable to be the countryId.

```
$countryId = get_the_ID();
```

then, use the variable in your cityArgs and in your townArgs.

Lastly, only use wp_reset_postdata ONCE...after your country loop is complete.

Comment: Adam - you are an absolute legend! That was exactly it, I was forgetting about the main query and assuming that wp_reset_postdata() was taking me back to the country loop. Many thanks!